# Visual Studio 2013 Installer Project can't save .vdproj file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vdproj, visual-studio-setup

I just downloaded and installed the Installer Projects extension for VS 2013 and tried to make a new .vdproj project.  I created new "Hello World" console application project, then added a new Visual Studio Installer project to the solution, added the output of the console project to it, and tried to build it.  Visual Studio opened a file save dialog and prompted me to save my .vdproj file.  When I clicked "Save", it complained that it could not find the file that it was prompting me to save.

Why can't I create this simple .vdproj project?  VS had no problem with saving the console application project files to this location.

[image: Could not find file]

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 with Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Project extension v.0.9.0 still has this issue even when running as Administrator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why, but if you go to the folder and manually create an empty file of the same name as your project, when you try to save, it will respond, "File exists, Overwrite?" and when you select [Yes], it creates the project without a problem.

Comment: Indeed, this worked for me too, and this is an easier solution.  I'll recommend you for the "Hacker" badge :-)

Comment: It didn't throw the "Overwrite?" dialog in my case...it just silently overwrote the file.

Comment: this worked.. previously had tried admin mode.. also undid read-only on folder.. but those did not do anything. funny when i was about to just try this to see what happens, i happened to stumble on this thread.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a permissions issue.  If I run Visual Studio "as Administrator" it works.

Comment: I am having the same problem on VS2010 also, can you send me a copy of a dummy VS2010 .vdproj file. Thanks.